# Reports with DOCX -> PDF format

Tags: java, pdf-generation, report, docx

I have to manipulate a docx document, just to replace some $variables, and need to convert it to PDF format before send it to the end user. I am using Java to develop a webapp with SpringFramework.

I've been searching on the web for some library that could help me on this task, I found one that seems to be in a early development stage called xdocreport. Do you know any other Java library for this task?

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-to-convert-ms-doc-to-pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most popular solutions is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) which can interpret and convert many MS document formats, and can output to PDF.

Comment: Suggest you have a look at docx4j; it supports several approaches to variable replacement, and built in PDF output.

Answer (score 6):

I'm one of developer of XDocReport. Your need is exactly the goal of XDocReport (replace $variable with Java value from docx and convert it to PDF/XHTML if you wish).

If you want play with XDocReport you have XDocReport online demo at http://xdocreport.opensagres.cloudbees.net/

Today there is no release (coming soon at June or May 2011) but I have start to write documentation for docx reporting http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMain . In this section you can download Eclipse project which provides XDocReport JARs (but pay attention, it's not the last version of XDocReport).

PDF conversion documentation will coming soon.

Comment: Please stop tagging questions with your product name. You're just spamming.

Comment: I have done that because the topic speak about xdocreport. I'm really sorry Collin. I stop that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use OpenOffice.org to open the DOCX and "print to PDF".  Their [Developers Guide can be found here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide).  And here's an ["Export to PDF" tutorial](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Tutorials/PDF_export).

Comment: using native libraries isn't the best choice for web apps

Comment: Unless its the only choice.  And a sufficiently portable native library can play with Java just fine.

Comment: thanks - will review the old questions and mark the answers.