# PDF Creation from a word template

Tags: pdf-generation, apache-poi

I have this requirement:

1. Generate a Word document from template using poi.jar. The generated doc will have dynamic values as well as the formatting needed.
2. Convert the generated doc as it is to PDF. I don't want to apply any formatting again while generating the PDF.

Is there any open source Java API available to do this?

Answer (score 4):

[OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) offers an [API](http://www.openoffice.org/api/) that can do the job for you.

Please note that this question has been answered many times on StackOverflow (and over the web), see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-to-convert-ms-doc-to-pdf) for example.

Comment: @user138748 - in the answer linked by Alexis the Docmosis library mentioned can provide template functionality from word docs.  Though if you have *already* solved that using POI, JODConverter might be what you want for the PDF bit.