# Conversion of word document to pdf in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, ms-word, dalvik

I know that there n number of question in stackoverflow which is about this same issue, but i didn't get what i was looking for. I even tried using `jwordconvert.jar` from `Qoppa` software, but alas !!! it said

```
Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
Conversion of dalvik format failed.
```

Now i have seen an app in android market, thats name as `Word To Pdf` from `ThinkTI.com.br`. It just did what i want my program to do.

So can anyone tell me about the **mechanism behind this application or a similar or better way to do it....**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-to-convert-ms-doc-to-pdf/3022553 - Have you tried all the libraries in the post?

Comment: That's because that JAR is no Android JAR. Android's JVM is a custom one, so it is not "pure" Java. And your question is too broad. You need 2 libraries for this: one to be able to read Word documents and one to write PDF documents. IIRC both formats are open, so you can write those libraries yourself.

Comment: With both formats are open (ish) neither format is easy. Plus can't you just dump Java JARs in a lib folder and the build tool will convert for you (assuming the JAR does not require something the Dalvik VM does not support)?

Comment: When are you getting the heap space exception, compile time or run time? If compile time see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space

Comment: This link will help you ... [https://github.com/plutext/docx4j](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j)

Answer (score 2):

**Disclosure: I work on docx4j**

docx4j can produce PDF output; see [ConvertOutPDF.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java)

If that quality is acceptable for your purposes, then you can use the docx4j Android build.  See [jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/)

You'll still need to give Java enough heap space; as per the blog post, to give Eclipse more heap space  (symptom is ‘you get Unable to execute dex: Java heap space’) edit eclipse.ini, with something like:

```
-Xms256m

-Xmx4096m
```

Comment: How to use it in Android APK ?