# How to convert MS doc to pdf in android

Tags: java, android, performance, pdf

This is what we want to achieve:

We have already evaluated the following commercial tools also.

- Aspose.Words - Dosent convert the MS word doc when you have Content control in the doc. We get the text "Click here to enter text" in place of the data. Also its super expensive.
- ABCPDF - converts the MS doc to PDF. But the tool internally calls MS word to achieve this. We can see the Winword.exe application running the task manager when executing the code. This I guess is something similar to server side automation of MS word which Microsoft does not support\recommend (Let me know if i am wrong).
- BullZip - converts the MS doc to PDF. Uses the print option to convert the document. This also may be using winword.exe for the conversion.

Does anyone know any other commercial tool that will work without using MS word in the back ground?

Comment: if it´s possible in your case, you could use an online service as last resort?

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902566/conversion-of-word-document-to-pdf-in-android