# WordtoPdf /PdftoWord in Android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

Anyone Know the code for converting  Word to PDF / PDF to Word in **ANDROID**...
      If you Know 
      Please Share me....
Already tried:

**Jars:**

> docx4j-3.0.0.jar

**Code:**

```
    try
    {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(
                new File("file1"));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "is", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .load(is);

        List sections = wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections();

        for (int i = 0; i < sections.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println("sections Size" + sections.size());
          /*  wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections().get(i)
                    .getPageDimensions().setHeaderExtent(3000);*/
        }

        Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper();

        PhysicalFont font = (PhysicalFont) PhysicalFonts.getPhysicalFonts().get(
                "Comic Sans MS");

        fontMapper.getFontMappings().put("Algerian", font);

        wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);
        PdfSettings pdfSettings = new PdfSettings();
        org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.PdfConversion conversion = new org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion(
                wordMLPackage);

       OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                "file1/sampleeee.pdf"));
        conversion.output(out, pdfSettings);



        System.err.println("Time taken to Generate pdf  "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I cant get the output...

Comment: related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-to-convert-ms-doc-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

One reason why you "cant get the output" is because you are providing an incorrect `FileOutputStream`. You need to be using either:

- [Internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (`openOutputStream()`, `getFilesDir()`, etc.), or
- [External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) (`getExternalFilesDir()`, etc.)

Comment: k..leave what I have tried...If you know the code to convert Word to Pd f  and Pd f to Word ...Please Share me...