# Java - Convert a docx to a pdf document

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a docx document containing a logo to a pdf document.
I have tried this :

```
FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(fileInput);
XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(in);
File outFile=new File(fileOutput);
OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(outFile);
PdfOptions options=null;
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document,out,options);
```

But in the pdf document the logo is not at the right place.

Is there a way to create a PDF that is exactly the same as the docx document?

Comment: Maybe works if the docx became a raster image and then putted in the PDF.

Comment: Consider going through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-to-convert-ms-doc-to-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Could be document4j an option? It delegates the convertion to the native application.

> This is achieved by delegating the conversion to any native application which understands the conversion of the given file into the desired target format.

```
File wordFile = new File( ... );
File target = new File( ... );
IConverter converter = ... ;
Future<Boolean> conversion = converter
    .convert(wordFile).as(DocumentType.MS_WORD)
    .to(target).as(DocumentType.PDF)
    .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
    .schedule();
```

You can quickly test if the convertion fit your requirement with the "Local demo" on a Windows machine with Word and Excel installed:

```
git clone https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j.git
cd documents4j
cd documents4j-local-demo
mvn jetty:run
```

Then go to http://localhost:8080

See the full documentation here :
http://documents4j.com/#/