# Convert docx to pdf using documents4j throw exception

Tags: java, documents4j

I am trying to write a converter for docx to pdf using the documents4j library. Is there any missiong libraries ? could it be a limitation of the documents4j library ?

This is the dependencies I am using :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-util-conversion</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-transformer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-util-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is the code for my converter :

```
    public static FileInputStream convert(InputStream docxInputStream) throws FileNotFoundException {

        IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
                .baseFolder(new File("C:\\"))
                .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(TEMP_PATH));

        converter.convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX)
                .to(fileOutputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF)
//                .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
                .schedule();

        return new FileInputStream(TEMP_PATH);


    }
```

I am gettng the below exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application was started without any registered or class-path discovered converters.
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.validate(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:68)
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.loadConfiguration(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:85)
    at com.documents4j.conversion.DefaultConversionManager.<init>(DefaultConversionManager.java:22)
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.makeConversionManager(LocalConverter.java:79)
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.<init>(LocalConverter.java:51)
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter$Builder.build(LocalConverter.java:186)
    at com.bnpparibas.sit.communication.historage.utilities.converting.DocxToPDFConverter.convert(DocxToPDFConverter.java:30)
```

Any idea about that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you define TEMP_PATH?

Comment: Yes, TEMP_PATH is present.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that this dependecy is missing :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and the conversion code should be written like below :

```
public static FileInputStream convert(InputStream docxInputStream) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(TEMP_PATH))) {
        IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();
        converter
                .convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX)
                .to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                .prioritizeWith(1000).schedule();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(TEMP_PATH);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return inputStream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Documents4j is best free api for convert docx to pdf.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-local</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Use the below code for convert docx to pdf.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;

public class Document4jApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File inputWord = new File("Tests.docx");
        File outputFile = new File("Test_out.pdf");
        try  {
            InputStream docxInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputWord);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();
            converter.convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and need installed ms office on server.

Comment: tnx , but it not support Persian and right to left languages. :)

Comment: Be AWARE. this is not working in UNIX based system.

Comment: @brebDev, Use this for linux/unix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022376/how-can-i-convert-a-word-document-to-pdf/65403145#65403145

Comment: I've made some tests with docx4j before using documents4j. And the generated pdf contains red labels in it like for ex: NOT IMPLMENTED: support for w:pict without v:imagedata or NOT IMPLMENTED: support for w:ptab.